# Highcharts repeated series from XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, highcharts

Ok so I am using Highcharts.JS on Quickbase to load XML data as data points, but I am having an issue with the series. Every time I try to add in a new series (co2 for example) it labels it as methane. I have tried doing the push along with methane, and also separated.

```js
< !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < meta http - equiv = "Content-Type"
content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" >
  < title > Basic Chart < /title>
  
  
  <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
  <script type="text/javascript
" src="
https: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  < script type = "text/javascript"
src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" > < /script>
  
  
  <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
  <script type="text/javascript
">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
   var sgaxml = 'https://EDITED.quickbase.com/db/EDITED?apptoken=EDITED&act=API_DoQuery&query=%7B14.EX.%27_FID_9%7D&clist=7.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.31.32.33.34.35.36.37'

   var options = {
    chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
     text: 'Components Over Time'
    },
    xAxis: {
     categories: [
     'Methane',
     'CO2',
     ]
    },
    yAxis: {
     title: {
      text: 'Units'
     }
    },
    series: []
   };
   
   // Load the data from the XML file 
   $.get(sgaxml, function(xml) {
    
    // Split the lines
    var $xml = $(xml);

    // push methane series
    $xml.find('record').each(function(i, record) {
     var seriesMOptions = {
      name: $(record).find('methane').text(),
      data: [],
     };
     
     // push Methane data points
     $(record).find('methane').each(function(i, point) {
      seriesMOptions.data.push(
       parseInt($(point).text())
      );
     });
     
     // add it to the options
     options.series.push(seriesMOptions);
    });
    
    // push co2 series
    $xml.find('record').each(function(i, record) {
     var seriesCOptions = {
      name: $(record).find('co2').text(),
      data: [],
     };
     
     // push CO2 data points
     $(record).find('co2').each(function(i, point) {
      seriesCOptions.data.push(
       parseInt($(point).text())
      );
     });
     
     // add it to the options
     console.log(seriesCOptions);
     options.series.push(seriesCOptions);
    });
    
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
   });
   
   
  });
      </script>
  
     </head>
     <body>
  
      <!-- 3. Add the container -->
  <div id="
container " style="
width: 800px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto "></div>
  
    

    
 </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have a clue as to why it is doing this ? It provides the right data, but is naming it/grouping it with the wrong series...I've looked up a few questions kind of close to this and followed the suggestions, but most of the time it was off in left field as far as what I know/am attempting to do.

Comment: Could you paste your XML, cause seems that https://EDITED.quickbase.com/db/EDITED?apptoken=EDITED&act=API_DoQuery&query=%7B14.EX.%27_FID_9%7D&clist=7.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.31.32.33.34.35.36.37 doesnt return something.

Comment: I originally meant to post the XML, I apologize for that    http://pastebin.com/3MqatmEb